# Is it possible to create games bundles on Windows platform (UWP)?

Tags: windows, uwp, bundle

We want to merge some of our games in bundle by game themes.
For example - you once buy a bundle and inside you get game1, game2 and game3.
Is it possible with UWP games, which targets Windows platform?
Can't find anything about that theme in google.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about distribution and packaging of UWP applications for use on Windows OS rather than an actual coding issue. Maybe reference to Microsoft Store would be more beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such feature in Microsoft Store that sells multiple games in a collection. This is currently not supported in Microsoft Store. I'd suggest you submit a feature in the feedback hub about this.